# What is the value expected on the voltmeter display

Tags: analog-to-digital

I am a complete beginner and i had some problems figuring out what i had to do to solve this. I apologize in advance for not putting the proper tags but i didnt know what to put in there or if even if this is the place to ask these types of questions. If not please tell me where i have to go to ask them.

I would be grateful if someone could tell me what formulas or the way to solve these types of exercises is.

So the exercise goes like this:

A square signal with amplitude between +5 V to +10 V and duty cycle equals to 0.25 is measured by a Peak voltmeter realized as a zero fixer (diode connected to the ground and series capacitor). What is the value expected on the voltmeter display?

The answer should be: 1.25

I already have the answer but i cant figure out how to do it.

I know how to do it if there is a TRMS voltmeter but in this case im lost.
In the TRMS case you use the formula

$V_{rms}=\sqrt{\frac1T\int_0^T{v^2(x)dt}}$ if im not mistaken.

I do realize that in here i need to post at least some of the work that i have done. But in this case im lost and i do need the help because the professor in our class doesnt have any examples with this case so i need something to work with.

Comment: Hi Ani- Please post your question here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/